# SSIS - check if database and tables exist, if not - run sql to create

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database

I am planning on importing data into Azure SQL database using SSIS package. I know I can do that with OLEDB Source and Destination but I also want to check if the database and tables exist and if not - create them. I am planning on using Execute SQL task to create database and tables, but how do I first check if they already exist?

So if database and tables exist, I will run data flow task to transfer the data, but if they do not exist - run Execute SQL task to create database and tables and then run data flow task.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Can you use ssdt for schema management task?  You can call sqlpackage.exe in an execute process task and it will deploy whatever does not exist.

Comment: Can I utilize it in my SSIS package?

Comment: Yes, any process can be executed from an Execute Process Task.  I'll post some more details in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an OLE DB connection manager to the server and master database on it.  Apply this connection manager for the next two steps.
2. Create two SQL tasks in a container.  The first SQL task will check to see if the database exists.  You can pass the database name as a variable to it and apply it in the SQL example like that shown below.  The "?" is the database name variable.

   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases where name=?)
   -- create database
3. Then for the second SQL task apply something like the following in which the database and table name are passed as variables.  But, in difference to the previous SQL, you can apply an expression for defining the SQL.

   "IF OBJECT_ID(N'" + <@DatabaseName> + "dbo." + <@tablename> + ", N'U') IS NULL
   CREATE TABLE " + <@DatabaseName> + "dbo." + <@tablename> + "
   (
       Field1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
       ,Field2 TINYINT NOT NULL
   );"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Azure or SSIS, but in SQL Server you can check to see if an object exists like this:

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.UserTable', 'U') IS NULL
  -- Doesn't Exist.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That was not my question, I am asking in terms of SSIS implementation

Comment: In SSIS you can create an OLE DB connection manager pointing to the server and the master database on it.  Using that connection manager,  apply the above SQL to search for any database.  Set up your database name in a global variable and pass that variable to the SQL as "?" as in the following example:  IF NOT Exists(Select * From sys.sysdatabases where name=?) <create database>.

Answer (score 0):

SSDT (the database tool, not the SSDT-BI product suite) uses a declarative model to manage and deploy database schemas.  You can get SSDT [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx).

Once you create a new SQL Server Database Project, you can import an existing database schema.  In the database properties, you will define your target database as Azure.  When you build the project, it creates a dacpac file as output.  This file is an archive that contains the definition of your database.

SSDT comes with a utility called sqlpackage.exe, which you can learn about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh550080(v=VS.103).aspx).  You can then pass in your dacpac file and target server and have the utility "publish" the database.  If the database and schema are there are match up, it will do nothing.  If it does not exist all objects will get created.  If the schema is different than expected, it will update the schema according to how it is defined in the project.

SSDT has loads more benefits than this, but for your case, it will simplify the process and make it far more maintainable.

BTW, if the database does not exist, you may need to put delay validation on your connection managers and tasks in the rest of the package so it does not fail validation.  Or better, create a master package that first executes the sqlpackage process task and then calls your loading package as a child package.

Comment: I already have SSDT, that's how I can create SSIS packages on the first place.

Comment: There is loads of confusion around these poorly named products that serve completely different purposes.  SSDT is for database design and testing.  SSDT-BI is for creating BI projects: SSIS, SSRS, SSAS.  Which version of visual studio are you using?  I'll get you a direct link

Comment: I actually need to use SSIS for my solution.  I really do not want to sidetrack to other tools

Comment: This is not avoiding using SSIS, SSIS will implement your solution by orchestrating the tasks and executing the process.  SSDT will handle the database schema.  Use the right tool for the right job.